# What is a Nicolai map?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I couldn't find the definition of a Nicolai map.

What is it and what is a simple example which helps understanding it?

Comment: They seem to have been thought up [here](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:153616:1/component/escidoc:153615/350983.pdf) and/or [here](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:153608:1/component/escidoc:153607/354825.pdf) (PDFs). At least that is where [this PDF](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/20/053/20053462.pdf) points to (p. 1).

Comment: More original articles by H. Nicolai: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(80)90460-5 http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90138-0 http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(82)90570-6

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16367/2451