# What is neuroavalanche and how does it relate to the idea of supersymmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry, differential-equations, chaos-theory, stochastic-processes

In a [wiki on stochastic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation), one passage regarding supersymmetry states the following:

> The spontaneous breakdown of... supersymmetry... explains the
>   associated long-range dynamical behavior, i.e, the butterfly effect,
>   1/f and crackling noises, and scale-free statistics of earthquakes,
>   neuroavalanches, solar flares etc.

What in tarnation is a neuroavalanche? How is it related to the breakdown of supersymmetry? And why is something so ominous sounding also so difficult to define using Google?

Comment: That wikipedia entry links to http://www.jneurosci.org/content/24/22/5216 (but the article doesn't seem to mention SUSY though).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform. Thank you. This helps me understand that avalanches are being used as analogy to neuro-synaptic cascade effects. I still have to wonder how SUSY crept in.

Comment: http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/256/256j.pdf first page. You replace an algebraic object (Jacobian determinant) with an integral over fermionic variables, and you have an equivalent equation that is now supersymmetric! It's miraculous and powerful. I learned about it on this site from Ron Maimon http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16397/1486

Comment: The wiki article reports on a new application of the supersymmetric representation, in which the breaking of supersymmetry leads to "dynamic long-range order". It's a cool enough topic to deserve a proper answer but I am not competent to write it.